# Bind window visibility with running state of a service in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, service, binding

I'm using a loading screen in my application while a service is running a task in another thread.
After the service is done, I would like to close the loading screen.
But instead of calling something like `window.hide()` every time, I would like to have a binding between the service state and the visibility of the window.

- Service runs --> loading screen visible
- Service runs not --> loading screen invisible

The service has properties like  `onRunningProperty()` or `runningProperty()` and the window has `onShownProperty()` or `showingProperty()` but I didn't manage to bind them.

How can I bind the visibility of the loading screen with the running state of a service, so that the loading screen is automatically shown, when the service runs and hidden, when the service is done?

Example:

HelloApplication.java

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

HelloController.java

```
public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    private final Service<Void> service = new Service<>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };

    public HelloController() {
        service.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            // now I want to hide the loading screen
            WaitController.waitController.waitLabel.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        });
    }

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
        service.restart();
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("wait.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 630, 400);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("New Window");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            WaitController.waitController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

WaitController.java

```
public class WaitController {

    @FXML
    Label waitLabel;

    public static WaitController waitController;
}
```

wait.fxml

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="291.0" prefWidth="428.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.test.WaitController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="waitLabel" layoutX="161.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="92.0" prefWidth="105.0" text="Wait..." textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

hello-view.fxml

```
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.test.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>

    <Label fx:id="welcomeText"/>
    <Button text="Hello!" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick"/>
</VBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to use bindings for this. There are no writable properties of `Window` that control whether or not it's showing. There is, of course, the `showing` property, but it is read-only. In other words, there's no appropriate property of `Window` that you can bind to the service's `running` property.

What you can do, however, is *listen* to the service's `running` property and call `show()` / `hide()` on the window instance as appropriate. For example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    var service = new ServiceImpl();
    setupWindowForService(primaryStage, service);

    var button = new Button("Start service");
    button.disableProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());
    button.setOnAction(e -> {
      e.consume();
      service.restart();
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(button), 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void setupWindowForService(Window owner, Service<?> service) {
    var window = new Stage();
    window.initOwner(owner);
    window.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    window.setTitle("Service Window");
    window.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(new Label("Service running...")), 300, 150));
    window.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
      if (service.isRunning()) {
        // prevents user from closing the window while service is
        // running. Perhaps it would make more sense to cancel the
        // service?
        e.consume(); 
      }
    });

    // the code that shows and hides the window based on the service's state
    service.runningProperty().addListener((obs, wasRunning, isRunning) -> {
      if (isRunning) {
        window.show();
      } else {
        window.hide();
      }
    });
  }

  private static class ServiceImpl extends Service<Void> {
    @Override protected Task<Void> createTask() {
      return new Task<>() {
        @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {
          int max = 3_000;
          for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1L);
          }
          return null;
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```